# Class design in .NET

Tags: .net

I'm in the design phase of a small project.I've an **activity** class and **resource** class.
Each activity can have multiple resources, So my question is should I create a collection of resources like `IList<resource>` and add it to `Activity` class or should I create some service class whose purpose is to assign resources to each activity

Regards,
Ravi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create both.

In your domain model, the Activity class should contain ICollection.

In your Service / Business Logic class, you should have ability to add.remove Resources from Activity

Assigning single responsibility to classes helps keeping your code clean and maintainable.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I think that at the end you should store the resources in the activity inside a collection. But, depending on the control you need to have over the append operation, you could append the resources directly or have some mechanism to append them.

That depends on your needs. If you don't need to control how resources are added to the activity whatsoever, then the collection only should be sufficient (and an accessors of course).

However, if you need to perform some sort of operation or track something about the process then you should have a method in Activity to append the resource to it, and in such method you would create your constraints/policies.

Also, if the activity should not know about other activity's resources and you still need to control them... then a 3rd class would be necessary to track them all.